# position and orient GameObject based on known coordinates

Tags: unity-game-engine

**Rewording for clarity**

I have a real world scan of an object and a 3d model of an object in the scene, basically two models that represent the same thing, but not the same by any means. Think of it like a model and a stick figure.

I want to overlay or "best fit" the objects to one another. I have multiple points/child objects that are easy to use for alignment.

Comment: This is an interesting problem, but I'm afraid the question is currently too broad to be adequately answered on Stack Overflow. Is the object guaranteed to be able to be oriented to touch all points, or is this a "best fit" scenario? How are the points generated? Are they arbitrary, or using information from the object? Does the object need to be scaled or just rotated? All of these will affect the algorithm complexity, and how sophisticated it really has to be.

Comment: So you want to rotate and reposition? For two GOs it's easy, you just set the .position and .rotation and this is it. If misunderstood something, please make a screenshot, or draw it or something for a better understand [EDIT: @Serlite is right if the items in question are complex, that can be an issue]

Comment: I agree that visual aids will certainly help reduce the ambiguity here. Please take the time to create a drawing or series of screenshots that represents your intentions.

Comment: thanks guys, I'll clarify shortly

Comment: this is a best fit scenario where a real world scan of an object and a 3d model of an object need to be aligned in the scene

Comment: Rob, based on the fixed text I'd say this is not a Unity question. It would be better to use a 3D editor tool for that, for example, Blender. Even if you can automate this somehow it'll never be a perfect fit and you'll end up manually editing and fixing up issues (e.g. wrong edge detections of the scanned object)

Comment: well, it has to be done on the fly and with code as the real world scans come it. It certainly would be easy to just manually position and rotate an object in an editor.  That being said, more of a scripting question for sure

Answer (score 0):

You will want to basically want to move the origin of your object to the target object after adjusting for difference in localposition.  You can then get Vectors from the know points such as A to B and A to C.  Then just rotate the object based on the difference.

here is my test code.  Seems to work

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Trangle
{
    public GameObject Master { get; set; }
    public GameObject p1 { get; set; }
    public GameObject p2 { get; set; }
    public GameObject p3 { get; set; }
    public GameObject p4 { get; set; }

    public Trangle(GameObject go)
    {
        Master = go;
        p1 = go.transform.Find("1").gameObject;
        p2 = go.transform.Find("2").gameObject;
        p3 = go.transform.Find("3").gameObject;
        p4 = go.transform.Find("4").gameObject;
    }

    public Vector3 GetRotation(GameObject point)
    {
        return p1.transform.position + point.transform.position;
    }

}

public class PositionTest : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Target;
    private Trangle _target;
    private Trangle _this;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        _target = new Trangle(Target);
        _this = new Trangle(gameObject);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (transform.position != TargetPosition())
        {
            SetPosition();
            return;
        }

        if (Vector3.Dot(_this.GetRotation(_this.p2), _target.GetRotation(_target.p2)) != 1)
        {
            var v1 = _this.GetRotation(_this.p2);
            var v2 = _target.GetRotation(_target.p2);
            var diff = Quaternion.FromToRotation(v1, v2);

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, diff, Time.deltaTime * 3f);
            return;

        }

        if (Vector3.Dot(_this.GetRotation(_this.p3), _target.GetRotation(_target.p3)) != 1)
        {
            var diff = Quaternion.FromToRotation(_this.GetRotation(_this.p3), _target.GetRotation(_target.p3));

            transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, diff, Time.deltaTime * 3f);
            return;
        }
    }

    void SetPosition()
    {
        float step = 4f * Time.deltaTime;

        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, TargetPosition(), step);
    }

    Vector3 TargetPosition()
    {
        return _target.Master.transform.position + new Vector3(_target.p1.transform.localPosition.x - _this.p1.transform.localPosition.x,
                                                            _target.p1.transform.localPosition.y - _this.p1.transform.localPosition.y,
                                                            _target.p1.transform.localPosition.z - _this.p1.transform.localPosition.z);
    }
}
```